# how to display three text fields on one line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display three textfields on one line. When screen is smaller then these textfields should be displayed in the same line. Currently when I make my browser smaller then textfields move to the second line.

How can I achieve this?

please see my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/6tkF8/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="fields">
    <input type="text" class="name" />
    <span>&ndash;</span>
    <input type="text" class="name" />
    <input type="text" class="name2" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fields {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    width: 23%;
}
.name {
    display: inline;
    width: 11ex;
}
.name2 {
    display: inline;
    width: 8ex;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify what you wish to happen when the fields don’t fit. By default, if you prevent line breaks, the content of the `div` element will visibly overflow outside the borders you draw, quite possibly over some other content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give **white-space:nowrap;** to your `.fields` DIV. Write like this:

```
.fields {
            border: 1px solid grey;
            width: 23%;
            white-space:nowrap;
        }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6tkF8/1/

Answer (score 0):

This solves your issue:

```
.fields {
  display: inline;
}
```